# how to install Emacs predictive-mode in Aquamacs?

Tags: emacs, aquamacs

I'm trying to install Emacs predictive-mode, but when I do `predictive-mode`, I get `Loading`completion-ui': old-style backquotes detected!`

Then I get: 
   `Wrong type argument: listp, word`

Backtrace:

http://pastebin.com/42nkiNYP

Comment: I googled the function name, and it seems like the error occurs at https://github.com/emacsmirror/completion-ui/blob/master/completion-ui.el#L3134 .  Not sure what to make of that, though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your completion-ui might require a tiny fix to adjust to the newer Emacs you're using.  Report this to the author of completion-ui (or predictive-mode).